# Why public enum are not allowed on the top class but are allowed inside the classes. Also non-public are allowed outside but not inside

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn enum and I saw that you can declare an enum on the top level (only when you are not saying it's public).

```
public class training{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Color.BLUE);
    }
}

enum Color{
    RED,GREEN,BLUE
}
```

But when I say it's public I have to do it inside the classes because outside it gives me error "The public type Color must be defined in it's own file"

I fix the error by saying it's not public:

```
public class training{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Color.BLUE);
    }
}

enum Color{
    RED,GREEN,BLUE
}
```

Why is this behaviour of enums?

Comment: You can only have one outer public per file, whether classes or enums.

Comment: This has nothing to do with enums. Only one top-level class, enum, or similar entity can be public in a file.

Comment: Please see [JLS §7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) regarding only allowing one top-level class per file. Note that an enum is considered a "restricted kind of class" as per [JLS §8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Comment: Another *reasoning*: a top-level public class/enum/record/interface must be saved in a file with the same name as that class/enum/record/interface (meaning of the error message "The public type Color must be defined in it's own file") -- so you can have a `public enum Color` and a non-public `class training` in a `Color.java` file. -- Obviously that also means that no two top-level public class/enum/record/interface  are allowed in the same file (the file cannot be named with both names)